# Using Breeze with server side paging enabled OData services

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

Breeze queries return an object containing results, information on the query fired, inline count and XHR. But as far as I have seen, nextLink is not captured when the OData service is configured to return data in several pages. Is there a way to send request to nextLink using the result of previous request instead of creating a query using skip and take?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the answer is that it does not support that at the current time. Perhaps @wardbell can chime in. While Breeze is designed to work "well" with OData as an underlying service type, it is not meant to be fully aligned with the OData spec and all of its features. It is really just leveraging OData as a standardized protocol for service-based CRUD patterns that it can ride on top of.

But server side paging is kind of important in OData, so hopefully they can add support for that at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Supporting OData Query on the MSDN

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

Scroll down to the Server Driven Pages topic and you will see that if you decorate your Get in the controller with a [Queryable(PageSize=10)] attribute, the returned JSON includes a

```
[Queryable(PageSize=10)]
public IQueryable<Product> Get() 
{
    return products.AsQueryable();
}
```

returns

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost/$metadata#Products",
  "value":[
    { "ID":1,"Name":"Hat","Price":"15","Category":"Apparel" },
    { "ID":2,"Name":"Socks","Price":"5","Category":"Apparel" },
    // Others not shown
  ],
  "odata.nextLink":"http://localhost/Products?$skip=10"
}
```

which you should be able to use to get the next page.  In your dataservice.js on your page, the result coming back from your call is JSON.

You should be able to use the .skip in your query parameters.

```
var getProducts = function (callback) {
    // get pageNumber from the viewModel
    var pageNumber = window.app.vm.Products.pageNumber();
    // ditto pageSize
    var pageSize = window.app.vm.Products.pageSize ();
    // set up your query
    var query4 = EntityQuery.from("Products")
        .orderBy("ProductName")
        .skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
        .take(pageSize);
    }
    // execute the query returning the promise from breeze and q
    // when the promise resolves, get the data and act on it
    return manager.executeQuery(query4)
        .then(function (data) {
             // set your viewModel ko.observableArray to the returned items
             window.app.vm.products.products(data.odata.value);
             // set your viewModel ko.observable to the pageNumber                                       window.app.vm.products.pageNumber(data.odata.nextlink.substring(indexOf("skip=") + 1) / pageSize);                 
        })
        .fail(queryFailed);
```

I just wrote this code off the top of my head, so you will need to inspect the returned data both in the browser F12 and in the dataservice.js to make sure you are correctly parsing out the skip value.   My code could easily be wrong because because I do not paged data in my SPA.  I am just suggesting this as an approach.

In my viewModel.activate() method, I would do something like this.

```
app.vm.products = (function ($, ko, dataservice, router) {
    var products = ko.observableArray();
    var pageNumber = ko.observable(1); 
    var pageSize = ko.observable(10);      
    var initialized = false;               // private

    var activate = function (routeData, callback) {
        if (initialized) {
            return;
        }
        initialized = true;
        dataservice.getProducts();
        // I do not think you will have an async timing issue here because the 
        //  get of the pageNumber happens before the ajax call
        //  which would be the major source of latency.
        // If you run into a problem with it updating too quickly you can start with 
        //  page number 0, or put the increment in a callback from the dataservice
        //  method.
        pageNumber(pageNumber() + pageSize);


    },
    ...

    return {
        activate: activate,            
        products: products 
    };
})($, ko, app.dataservice, app.router);
```

Like I said, I wrote this code in the response and have not tested it, but it should give you enough to determine the best for your app.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. I just started playing around with Breeze and want to know if there built-in is support for handling server-side paging. As Brian Noyes stated, there is no built-in support. So we have to handle the things manually. I understood the approach you tried putting up here, I will definitely give it a try. I would like to know if Breeze team is planning to include this feature its future release.